# Premiere Pro: How to match splits between two clips?

Tags: premiere

Premiere newbie, just trying to learn how to be productive. :)

I have 4 tracks

- Live Video File (+ bad audio)
- Screenflow capture
- Good audio

Since I had to wait for a Screenflow to render an export I synchronized my good audio with my video and began splitting so that I could sift quickly once the screenflow export was ready for import.

I've now synced my screen capture in the timeline, but I have to re-split.

**I'd like to split it in exactly the same places** as the other files.

[image: tracks with and without splits side by side]

1. Is there some sort of hotkey or script I can create to split one track to match where another is already split?
2. Is there I can make the magnet sticky to splits so that I don't have to zoom in and out for each split I'm re-creating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways this can be achieved:

- Holding the Shift key while scrubbing the timeline marker with the mouse.
- Holding the Shift key and using the up and down arrows to move between clips. This gives more precision over using the Shift key and scrubbing.
- Double clicking between two adjacent clips. For me this can be quicker when there are many clips and cuts and no shortcut keys are required.

Ctrl + K will cut all selected tracks and Ctrl + Shift + K will cut all tracks from the playhead.

Answer (score 0):

> 2. Is there I can make the magnet sticky to splits so that I don't have to zoom in and out for each split I'm re-creating?

By trial and error I was able to figure out that `holding shift` while moving on the timeline - either by dragging the timeline cursor, with with the cut tool (`c`) - will cause it to become magnetic or sticky to the splits in the clips.

Likewise `shift+cmd+k` will cut all tracks whereas `cmd+k` will cut only the highlighted track.